# Can I add a fragment to a FragmentActivity outside of whats in the viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm new to fragments. I have an activity that extneds FragmentActivity and uses the ViewPager to swipe between fragments.

Within one of the fragments I want to launch a new fragment that is "outside" of whats in the view pager. Is it possible to add a fragment like this or do I need to start a new activity with the fragment.

Now I have it launch a new activity but it is very slow.

Activity A
Fragment A
Fragment B
Fragment C

Activity B
Fragment D
Fragment A

So fragment A can launch acitvity B to get to fragment D but ideally it would be cool if I could just inject fragment D in Activity A

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but I strongly suggest you avoid it, unless you have a good reason to do so.

The ViewPager is (I assume) hosted in your Activity. The ViewPager obtains its views from its adapter. (A FragmentStateAdapter or similar). So you could tell the activity to change its layout (and or hide the Viewpager and show another FrameLayout) or you can simply launch another Activity that contains a single fragment. This is also fine.

Messing with the ViewPager/Adapter is usually complicated and you may waste time trying to make it work.

On the other hand, you could add the Fragment to the ViewPager's Adapter and use the getType of the adapter to return a different type of Fragment.

So you could do (pseudo code):

```
mPagerAdapter.addFragmentDToTheDataAtPositionZero(); //longFancyName ;)
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
```

that'd add Fragment D to the "top" of the viewpager and will switch to it.

Your Adapter then has to use an Interface to determine what type of fragment must be instantiated…

The getItem of the adapter would look like… (again, pseudocode)

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int i) {

        final FragmentTypeInterface f = yourData.get(i);

        if (f.isD()) {
            return FragmentD.newInstance();
        } else {
            return OtherFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

And so forth… :)